# NSTimer is not firing the scheduled method

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstimer

My code is given below.I am trying to show a counter on the screen in a window and enable a button after count limit is over.

When I run the code before nstimer and after nstimer are printed only once and nothing is printed from the time countdown function.Someone pelase help me.

```
- (void)startTimer:(NSInteger)count;
{
    NSLog(@"Entered the start timer function");
    self.countLimit = count;
    [self.lbCount setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",self.countLimit]];


    NSLog(@"Before nstimer");


    @try{

     self.timeCounter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timeCountDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    @catch (NSException* e) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[e description]);
    }
    NSLog(@"After nstimer");

}

- (void)timeCountDown
{
NSlog(@"Entered the function");
  self.countLimit = self.countLimit - 1;
    NSLog(@"Just entered the function time countdown");
    if (self.countLimit < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Entered count limit less than 0");
        [self.timeCounter invalidate];
        self.timeCounter = nil;
        [self.btContinue setEnabled:YES];
        return;
    }
    [self.lbCount setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",self.countLimit]];


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed in the [API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), your scheduled method must take a `NSTimer *` parameter:

```
- (void)timeCountDown:(NSTimer *)timer
```

Don't forget to change your selector in the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` call to reflect this:

```
// There's a colon after selector name to denote
// the method takes one parameter
self.timeCounter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
    target:self selector:@selector(timeCountDown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass as a arguement NSTimer* then use below after your timer

```
[self.timeCounter fire];
```

Comment: This won't have the scheduled delay though so it's of no use to him.